# Want to parameterize cronjob schedule on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron, jobs, schedule

I have an yaml. I want to parameterize the schedule of that kubernetes cronjob. On environment file I declared JobFrequencyInMinutes: "10"

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scheduled-mongo-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/$(JobFrequencyInMinutes) * * * *"
concurrencyPolicy: "Forbid"
jobTemplate:
spec:
   template:
     spec:
          containers:
          - name: scheduled-mongo-cronjob
            image: xxxx
          env:
          - name: JobFrequencyInMinutes
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: JobFrequencyInMinutes
                name: env-conf
```

When I am applying the above yaml I am getting an error.
The CronJob "scheduled-mongo-cronjob" is invalid: spec.schedule: Invalid value: "*/$(JobFrequencyInMinutes) * * * *": Failed to parse int from $(JobFrequencyInMinutes): strconv.Atoi: parsing "$(JobFrequencyInMinutes)": invalid syntax

Please guide me if there is any alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: I believe your issue is with the parenthesis. Could you try to change in the schedule from  `$(JobFrequencyInMinutes)` to `$JobFrequencyInMinutes` and let me know if it works?

Comment: I got the highlighted error. Looks like issue is with the conversion of string to integer. But environement value on yaml is forcing to be declared as string. **The CronJob "scheduled-mongo-cronjob" is invalid: spec.schedule: Invalid value: "*/$JobFrequencyInMinutes * * * *": Failed to parse int from $Schedule: strconv.Atoi: parsing "$JobFrequencyInMinutes": invalid syntax**

Comment: It seems that the environment variable is not being used, and that's causing the error, because `$JobFrequencyInMinutes` is not an INT... Actually it seems that the value is not even being converted, otherwise you would get "10" is not an INT. Could you try running the following to validate if the environment variable can be used there?
`kubectl run hello --schedule="*/$JobFrequencyInMinutes * * * *" --restart=OnFailure --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c "date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster"`.

If it runs could you get the result of: `kubectl get cronjob hello` to validate the schedule?

Comment: I got this error now. **The CronJob "hello" is invalid: spec.schedule: Invalid value: "*/ * * * *": Failed to parse int from : strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax**

Comment: Makes sense, the env variable will be just available when the CronJob is created and inside the job itself, but it is failing to create because the variable `$JobFrequencyInMinutes` does not exists in the node level.  I would say that to achieve what you are trying to do, you would need to have an env variable at cluster lvl, and update it and the job whenever you want to update the schedule. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand it. Please let me know how to create an environment variable at the cluster level instead of node level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211049/discussion-between-user3521701-and-juliano-costa).

Comment: Lets try to see if it works first... On your cluster node run the following: `JobFrequencyInMinutes=10`, simple as that, then try again to create your CronJob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the environment variable will be just available when the CronJob is created and inside the job itself, but it is failing to create because the variable $JobFrequencyInMinutes does not exists in the node level.

I would say that to achieve what you are trying to do, you would need to have an environment variable at cluster level. Whenever you want to update your schedule, you would need to set a new value to it and then re-create your CronJob.

It seems though that the declarative way it's not working (via your YAML), so you would need to create using the imperative way:

`kubectl run scheduled-mongo-cronjob --schedule="*/$JobFrequencyInMinutes * * * *" --restart=OnFailure --image=xxxx`

Comment: Thank you Juliano for suggesting a way to pass the variable. I will spend a little more time on this and see if there is a way I can do this from YAML. If I find none, I think the best answer I have is your's so far. Thanks again!